# Looping thru one table and assign ID to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table of Clients (id, clientName), and table of tasks (id, taskName).
Lets say that client table have about 200 rows and tasks about 700 000 rows. 
I need to assign every client about 300 tasks every day (with Job).
My idea is to make third table ClientXrefTask (idxref, fkClient, fkTask, date), and every night to fill that table with data 
(I need to have assign history so I choose third table)

Is there a better way to do this other then cursos (iterate thru clients, and insert in ClientXref table) ?

Comment: Will the clients ever complete all tasks, or would this be never ending?  You might want to show some sample data.

Comment: How do you find the 300 tasks to assign?

Comment: In XrefTable there is also flag for done tasks, all tasks (not existing in xref) are Candidates to assign (no specific order).

Answer (score 0):

You can add `fkClient` and `date` to the `tasks` table if those tasks are not getting changed once assigned.

Comment: I need to have assign history, that is the problem

Comment: Yes that’s what I mentioned if that is not getting changed once it is assigned, so you can achieve what you want. But if tasks are getting re-assigned then you might need to have a seperate table.